# How do I find the minimum percentage of students liking at least $3$ of the sports?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, percentages

I have done every method I know of. The teacher said it took him 2 weeks. I am completely lost.

In a middle school, $79\%$ of the students like basketball, $64\%$ like volleyball, $49\%$ like tennis, $81\%$ like swimming, and $89\%$ like soccer. What is the minimum percentage of students who like $3$ or more sports?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works...

Try stripping away the percents, assume there are 100 students in the school:

- 89 like soccer
- 81 like swimming
- 79 like basketball
- 64 like volleyball
- 49 like tennis

What's the smallest number of students who like 3 or more sports?

Summing, we get 89 + 81 + 79 + 64 + 49 = 362, so the average student likes 3.62 sports.

To minimize the total number of students liking 3 or more sports, you will want students that like 3 or more to like as many as possible.  And if they like less than 3, they might as well like 2 to eat up as many liked sports as possible.

If the 49 students who like tennis also like the other 4 sports, that's 49 students who like all 5.  They're consuming the maximum number of liked sports 5 * 49 = 245 that 49 students could.

That leaves 117 remaining liked sports and 51 remaining students.

We could have 8 students like the four remaining sports, but not tennis.  That eats up 4 * 8 = 32 more liked sports.

So at this point we've accounted for 245 + 32 = 277 of the 362 liked sports with 49 + 8 = 57 kids.  We have 85 liked sports to go for 43 kids.  42 of them can like 2 sports each and one kid can like just 1 sport.

That gives you a minimum of 57 kids that like at least three sports.

Ultimately, either of these are possible:

- 49% 5 sports
- 8% 4 sports
- 0% 3 sports
- 42% 2 sports
- 1% 1 sport

Or:

- 49% 5 sports
- 7% 4 sports
- 1% 3 sports
- 43% 2 sports
- 0% 1 sport

57% like 3 sports either way.

Comment: The answer our teacher gave us was 56.5% so this may be right. Can you explain where the 8 students came from? After you you got the 117 students with 51 remaining

Comment: I think your teacher is correct, and my simplification for the case with a school of 100 kids works for that case.  The 8 students came from trying to leave it so that the remainder could each like two sports, except for that one that I had left over.  Had I started with 200 kids (or just worked with percents!), the numbers would've worked out a little more nicely.  The 1% with 3 sports or the 1% with 1 sport are where I have my 0.5% of waste.  I think it should be: 49% 5 sports; 7.5% 4 sports; 43.5% 2 sports.